# Knockout Loop with Razor Validation

Tags: razor, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm trying to use Razor's validation with Knockout JS.

Using the standard razor approach of

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
```

I can get this working when working with a single item. However, I'm working with inline edits and a collection of items, displayed in a foreach list;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <!-- ko foreach: observables.PageItems-->
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="value: $data.Name"></span></td>
            <td><a data-bind="click: $root.update.bind($data)">@Res.Resource.Update</a></td>
            <td><a href='#' data-bind="click: $root.remove.bind($data)">@Res.Resource.Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
}
```

When, for example, the Update button is clicked, the following method will be checked;

```
this.validate = function () {
    var form = $("form");

    form.removeData('validator');
    form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

    return form.valid();
};
```

The issue is, whenever the first item in the list is invalid, every item's validation message is shown. If the first items name is blank, each item is given a warning, not just the first.
At the same time, any item after the first being invalid when it's submit is clicked, it will not display any validation message, only if it's the first item.

This is having a single form covering the entire foreach loop.

Is there a way around this?

I was considering having the form within the KO foreach loop, each having a id based on the index, and when the item is submitted checking it that individual form is valid. Does this sound like something that is worth exploring?

Comment: if you're using KO w/ Razor...this is you've really got to go one way or another with validation. When generating dynamic elements on the client side w/ KO, Razor doesn't know about them.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'll now take a different approach to the problem.